# Proper curve over any base is projective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it true that any proper morphism of relative dimension$\leq 1$ is projective (no additional assumptions whatsoever)? Is it true that any such morphism is $H$-projective (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W8)?

Is there a published reference containing a complete proof?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  That is false, and Piotr Achinger explained the issue in a recent comment.  Begin with a projective K3 surface that admits an elliptic fibration over $\mathbb{P}^1$.  For a very general first order deformation of the surface and its fibration to $\mathbb{P}^1$, the surface is not projective.

Comment: @JasonStarr does the fibration deform to the non-projective surface? which complex algebraic K3s admit elliptic fibration?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  The scheme is proper and smooth of relative dimension $2$ over $S=\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}[\epsilon]/\langle \epsilon^2 \rangle$, and it admits a proper, flat morphism of relative dimension $1$ to $\mathbb{P}^1_S$.  The scheme is not projective over $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @JasonStarr are there counterexamples if the base is irreducible and admits a morphism to $\mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{F}_p$?